# file chooser for download appears only after closing node.js

Tags: html, node.js, download, anchor

I have a very simple node.js app which successfully processes a file (from formidable form) but the download of the result file fails.  The download html

`<p><input type="text" value = "tx-AllSerums.xlsx"><br>
<a href="/transformed/tx-AllSerums.xlsx" 
download="All Serums.xlsx">Download transformed file</a>
</p>`

The result files are written to the directory structure from where I run node (the 'transformed' dir is in the dir in which I run node).
When I click on the above href I get console output but no file save dialog. (Should the server even get this event?)
When I kill the node server, up pops the file save dialog.  Of course the save fails: Network error.
I'm currently running everything on my workstation: Ubuntu 18.04; Chrome 70.0.3538.77, node v10.13.0

I've found that the file save dialog does appear but a very long time after the click.  But the server is still up and the save operation still fails: Network error.

Adding res.end() to the block catching the download click gets the dialog up immediately.  Now I successfully download a zero length file.  Oddly I find that encouraging.

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require("util");
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var java = require("java");
var proc = require("process");

java.classpath.push("/home/u0138544/fake/prep-1.jar");
java.classpath.push("/home/u0138544/fake/SRTDependancies-1.jar");
console.log(proc.cwd());
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    txName = "";
    if (req.url == '/fileupload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        var form = formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        var excelFilePath;
        var origName;
        form.parse(req , function (err, fields, files) {
            excelFilePath = files.filetoupload.path;
            console.log("upload " + excelFilePath);
            origName = files.filetoupload.name;
            txName = "tx-" + origName.replace(/\s/g, "");
            console.log( "txname = " + txName);
            //just for formatter
            var clz = "edu.utah.camplab.xlsx.SampleReportTransformer";
            var tx = java.newInstanceSync(clz);
            java.callMethodSync(tx, "run", excelFilePath, "./transformed/" + txName);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write('<p>');
            res.write('<input type="text" value = "' + txName +'"><br>');
            res.write('<a href="transformed/' + txName + '" download="' + origName +'">Download transformed file</a></p>');
            return res.end();
        });
    }
    else if (req.url.includes('transformed') && 
        req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        console.log("download attribute doesn't work")
        res.end();
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload" label="Pick a file"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end();
    }
}).listen(15080);
```

Comment: Can you post your node code?

Comment: @Phix: I certainly would be the SO formatter is giving me grief.  I may have to post an "answer"

Comment: ^would be^would but^.  Finally got the quotes right.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used java in node before, but I would suggest looking at using express to help with some of this.

Comment: The java part works: input files are correctly transformed and written to the "transformed" dir.  I'm loath to add another module in fear of making this node stuff an even blacker box. ;) What would be the immediate point/benefit of adding express?

Comment: My son fixed this for me.  I needed to tell node my "static" location.  I added express and this particular line: app.use('/transformed', express.static('transformed')); Works like a charm